# Laravel 7 what's less verbose code on multiple authorizations in gates?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm defining gates in `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` for user roles. Users has a value for their role. `like : (1,2,3,4)` The roles giving in user management and all users can have multiple authorizations.

The user roles is:

- Personnel Edit (value = 1)
- Add institution (value = 2)
- User Management (value = 3)
- Adding Record (value = 4)

To hide some information from the sidebar, I'm using  Blade directives `(@can)` .
I need to hide sections from the sidebar according to the authorization of each user.

The worked and long way I use is this :

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
....

        Gate::define('personnel-method', function ($user) {
        if(in_array(1,explode(",",$user->yetki)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    });

    Gate::define('add-method', function ($user) {
        if(in_array(2,explode(",",$user->yetki)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    });

    Gate::define('user-method', function ($user) {
        if(in_array(3,explode(",",$user->yetki)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    });

    Gate::define('adding-method', function ($user) {
        if(in_array(4,explode(",",$user->yetki)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    });

.....
```

sidebar.blade.php:

```
<ul>
 @can('personnel-method') <li>Personnel Edit </li> @endcan
 @can('add-method') <li>Add institution</li>@endcan
 @can('user-method')<li>User Management</li>@endcan
 @can('adding-method') <li>Adding Record</li>@endcan
</ul>
```

So Is there a less verbose code to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "fast"? Less verbose code?

Comment: Yes a method with less verbose code. And do you think is this code correct?

Comment: like `return in_array(4,explode(",",$user->yetki));` ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier thanks for tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting). You can either use the "array" cast and change the value in the database to JSON (`[1,2,3,4]`) or define a [custom cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) which splits the string up.

Using the `array` cast:

```php
class User extends Model {

  protected $casts = [
    'yetki' => 'array',
  ];

  //...
}
```

So you can change the gates to:

```php
Gate::define('personnel-method', function ($user) {
  if(in_array(1, $user->yetki))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
});
```

And since you're checking for a boolean, you don't have to use an `if` and just return the condition:

```
Gate::define('personnel-method', function ($user) {
  return in_array(1, $user->yetki);
});
```

To make it even easier to read you can move that logic to a method on the `User` class:

```
class User extends Model {
  public function hasRole($role)
  {
    return in_array($role, $this->yetki);
  }
}
```

Finally, you can define the roles in a class:

```
abstract class UserRole {
  const Personnel_Edit = 1;
  const Add_institution = 2;
  const User_Management = 3;
  const Adding_Record = 4;
}
```

And change the gates to:

```
Gate::define('personnel-method', function ($user) {
    return $user->hasRole(UserRole::Personnel_Edit);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To shorthand your code you can do the following

```
    Gate::define('personnel-method', function ($user) {
        return in_array(1,explode(",",$user->yetki));
    });

    Gate::define('add-method', function ($user) {
        return in_array(2,explode(",",$user->yetki));
    });

    Gate::define('user-method', function ($user) {
        return in_array(3,explode(",",$user->yetki));
    });

    Gate::define('adding-method', function ($user) {
        return in_array(4,explode(",",$user->yetki))
    });
```

If you're using php 7.4 you can also use arrow function

```
    Gate::define('personnel-method', fn ($user) =>  in_array(1,explode(",",$user->yetki)));
    Gate::define('add-method', fn ($user) => in_array(2,explode(",",$user->yetki)));
    Gate::define('user-method', fn ($user) =>  in_array(3,explode(",",$user->yetki)));
    Gate::define('adding-method', fn ($user) => in_array(4,explode(",",$user->yetki)));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to upgrade the PHP version because development is being made with my teammates. Thank you very much for your interest and help.